# how to open splash screen on button click android before opening new activity?

Tags: android, splash-screen

In the Main Activity I have  Buttons. Now i want a splash screen to be shown before the second activity opens when any of the button is clicked.. found about splash screen shown before mainactivity but didnt find anything about splash screen on button click before  second activity opens!! help needed
[This my Main Activity layout I want to open a splash screen before any of 2nd activity begins.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51KiJ.png)

Comment: why was i given a negative marking? i am desperately in need of help.

Comment: you can start splash activity as simple activity on button click using intent. If you didn't understand how to do it then tell what is your problem completely

Comment: public void OnclickButtonListener() {


       nw=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageNewsbtn);

        nw.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                  public void onClick(View v){


                            Intent intent=new Intent("np.edu.thebritishcollege.thebritishcollege.newsactivity");
                              startActivity(intent);

                    }
                }
 . this is my on click which opens a new activity. now how do i open a splash screen before this activity opens. i have a splash.java file

Comment: Should you ever wonder again why your questions get down voted, go read the help section. You'll find that unclear questions that ask why code is not working without including the said code are actually frowned upon. To be fair, you *were* asked to take the tour and read the rules when you registered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to open Splash Screen first

```
Intent intent=new Intent("this,Splash.class");
startActivity(intent);
```

Then you can start second activity from Splash Screen.

This piece of code should be placed into splash.java.

```
Intent intent=new Intent("np.edu.thebritishcollege.thebritishcollege.newsactivity"); startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Okay, you can upvote and accept answer if you have got any help

Comment: you can right this answer and press up button to upvote also, if you think it wuld be helpful to you.